# SFTP SSH.NET DLL instead of SharpSSH

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sftp, sharpssh

I was seeking for a free DLL for .net to handle SFTP connections.

I found out this project [SharpSSH](https://bitbucket.org/mattgwagner/sharpssh), but it lacks of documentation.

I spent a lot of time to figure how the dll works. I created a test project and I started to test different functions. Some functions are working such as deleting files.

I have a problem with putfile() function and getfile().

Here an example :

```
Dim ssh As SFTPUtil
ssh = New SFTPUtil("MY SERVER", "MY USER", "MY PW")
ssh.GetFile("/home/sftptest/test111.xml", "C:\\text.xml")
```

Note that the getfile() parameters are:

```
Public Sub GetFile(remotePath As String, localPath As String)
```

I step in the functions, but I didn't get the correct way to pass those parameters.

I dont really know if i should use slashes(/) or backslashes (). I know that Linux uses (/)

I noticed for example that the "C:\" has been transformed to "C:\\".

Just to mention that the SFTP is on a linux machine.

thank you.

Comment: remember that you also have SSHnet http://sshnet.codeplex.com/

Which is quite an improovement upon the java based sharpSSH

Comment: I try it, not able to make the connection. I call sftp = New SftpClient("server", "sftptest", "sftptest") which is SftpClient. And then, I do sftp.Connect(). And it fails. I got the net 4.0 dll version. I get the message error : No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication.

Comment: do you have a host to connect to? just to make sure use putty and connect to check if the connection exist.

SftpClient sftp = New SftpClient(string IP, string Username, string Password);
sftp.Connect();

Comment: I tried with putty, it s working... Any other hints :)

Comment: I found out that I have to activate keyboard-interactive authentication. I ill find to figured it out.

Comment: You've gone with the other project now, but the source for SharpSSH is available from the link you provided and [ChannelSftp.cs](https://bitbucket.org/mattgwagner/sharpssh/src/260e9d6d1bcf/SharpSSH/jsch/ChannelSftp.cs) shows it is hard coded to use slashes(/) for remote paths and `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` (\\) for local paths. Unfortunately on a quick look it seems it doesn't continue to use the `Path` API when manipulating local paths (at least).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I debugged yesterday in [ChannelSftp.cs](https://bitbucket.org/mattgwagner/sharpssh/src/260e9d6d1bcf/SharpSSH/jsch/ChannelSftp.cs) and I found out that sometimes, it crashes in the GetPathAttributes() function. The error handling is very bad IMAO, in the SharpSSH project. I switched to SSH.net and it's working like charm. I'm able to upload, download, delete etc, it's a powerful library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's What I should have done (vb.net code) to establish the connection with [THIS library (**SSHnet**)](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/), I did **not** use SharpSHH:

```
Private Sub ButtonAction_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonAction.Click

    Dim PasswordConnection = New PasswordAuthenticationMethod("test", "test")
    Dim KeyboardInteractive = New KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod("test")
    Dim ConnectionInfo = New ConnectionInfo("192.168.1.1", 22, "test", PasswordConnection, KeyboardInteractive)

    AddHandler KeyboardInteractive.AuthenticationPrompt, _
    Sub(_sender As Object, _e As Renci.SshNet.Common.AuthenticationPromptEventArgs)
        For Each prompt In _e.Prompts
            Debug.Print(prompt.Request)
            If Not prompt.Request.IndexOf("Password:", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) = -1 Then
                prompt.Response = "test"
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    sftp = New SftpClient(ConnectionInfo)
    sftp.Connect()

    sftp.disconnect()
End Sub
```

Comment: I have used the free SSH.NET but eventually used [component pro sftp](http://www.componentpro.com/sftp.net/) because SSH.NET lacked some advanced features and we needed quick support.

Answer (score 1):

This library is full of bugs. I downloaded version at 11/2012 and I have big problem even with simple function like Disconnect. Application will freeze and you have to restart it.

Comment: And 'This library...' is? Which one?

Comment: SharpSSH is full of bug. Use SSH.NET

Answer (score 0):

I have some problem understanding what exactly you want so here is an example code from the SSH.NET package. (NOT SharpSSH)

```
string IP = "192.168.1.1", User = "Testuser", Pass = "123";
SftpClient sftp;

private void UploadFileSFTP()
    {
        sftp = new SftpClient(IP, User, Pass);
        sftp.Connect();
        Uploader();
        Downloader();
        sftp.Disconnect();
    }

string FilePath="C:\\folder\\", Filename = "Filename.extention", 
       DeliveryPath = "/tmp/";

private void Uploader()
    {
        using (var file = File.OpenRead(FilePath + Filename))
        {
            sftp.UploadFile(file, DeliveryPath + Filename);
        }
    }

//there is possibly a simpler way to download but this is how i did it.
string FromPath = "/tmp/testfile.txt", StoragePath = ""; 
private void Downloader()
    {
        if (File.Exists(StoragePath))
            File.Delete(StoragePath);
        if (!Directory.GetDirectories(Path.GetTempPath()).Contains("WorkFiles"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetTempPath() + "WorkFiles");
        }

        StoragePath = Path.GetTempPath() + "WorkFiles\\testFile.txt";

        Int64 iSize = sftp.ReadAllBytes(FromPath).Length;
        Int64 iRunningByteTotal = 0;
        using (Stream streamRemote = sftp.OpenRead(FromPath))
        {
            using (Stream streamLocal = new FileStream(StoragePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                int iByteSize = 0;
                byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[iSize];
                while ((iByteSize = streamRemote.Read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    streamLocal.Write(byteBuffer, 0, iByteSize);
                    iRunningByteTotal += iByteSize;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I found out the solution : [here](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/discussions/361314), I have to set a keyboard-interactive authentication. I have the c# code, and I can't translate it to vb.net, lol.

Comment: I can't post out my answer because, I'm new and I don't have enough reputation, in other words, I'm a noob :p.

Comment: I wonder why they don't use sftp.DownloadFile() in this example ?

Comment: i didn't simply because this is a piece of code i had laying around.