# FtpWebRequest only return file names with ListDirectoryDetails

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I found one code very useful, but the following code return the names of directories and files from one FTP server, I need get the only the names of files.

```
ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest) FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + directory);
/* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
/* When in doubt, use these options */
ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
/* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
/* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse) ftpRequest.GetResponse();
/* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
/* Get the FTP Server's Response Stream */
StreamReader ftpReader = new StreamReader(ftpStream);
/* Store the Raw Response */
string directoryRaw = null;
/* Read Each Line of the Response and Append a Pipe to Each Line for Easy Parsing */
try{
     while (ftpReader.Peek() != -1){
        directoryRaw += ftpReader.ReadLine() + "|";
     }
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
      //Do something
 }
...
...
...
```

I investigate, but `WebRequestMethods.Ftp` has only `ListDirectory` and `ListDirectoryDetails`, both return the names of directories and files :(..

Someone can help me ..

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just use [`Path.GetFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Where?, in the FTP?  I think GetFileName is for local files

Comment: Try `Path.GetFileName("ftp://127.0.0.1/folder/filename.txt")` :o)

Comment: Use sshnet check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781808/sftp-ssh-net-dll-instead-of-sharpssh/11795754#11795754

Comment: [How to List Directory Contents with FTP in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298922/how-to-list-directory-contents-with-ftp-in-c)

Comment: Do you get file details, if you login with a regular FTP client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method to get object names of ftp always return the complete list (directories and files). I limit the names by extension, for example

```
var xmlFiles = files.FindAll( foo => foo.ToUpper().Contains( ".XML" )|| foo.ToUpper().Contains( ".TXT" ));
```

Comment: This might be a useful *comment* to my answer. But it's definitely not a *standalone answer* to question *"only return file names with ListDirectoryDetails"*.

Answer (score 1):

The `ListDirectory` issues `NLST` command to the server that returns file names only.

The `ListDirectoryDetails` issues `LIST` command to the server that commonly returns file names with details.

But it's ultimately up to the server, what it returns. If it returns filenames only for both, the `FtpWebRequest` cannot do anything about it.

It's possible that the server supports `MLSD` command to returns file details, but `FtpWebRequest` does not support that. Another alternative use to use `GetFileSize` and `GetDateTimestamp` for each file separately. But that's slow.

See also my answer at [Retrieving creation date of file (FTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4454281/850848#30306029).