# SharpSSH exception when trying to upload file to SFTP remote server

Tags: c#, file-upload, sftp, sharpssh

So this is my code, i basically copied and pasted from SharpSSH website.

```
Sftp oSftp = new Tamir.SharpSsh.Sftp(_ftpURL, _UserName, _Password);
oSftp.Connect(_Port);
oSftp.Put(LocalDirectory + "/" + FileName, _ftpDirectory + "/" + FileName);
oSftp.Close();
```

When i run this, i get a "first chance exception" on `oSftp.Connect(_Port)`

```
A first chance exception of type 'Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.JSchException' occurred in Tamir.SharpSSH.dll
```

Does anyone experienced with SharpSSH have any idea why this is happening? I have also tried uploading files to the server using Rubex but it gave me the same error.

Comment: If I was you I would change technology, I would use SSHNET over SharpSsh. Here's a link that may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781808/sftp-ssh-net-dll-instead-of-sharpssh

Comment: Aren't you by chance trying to connect to FTPS server with SFTP? What is your port number?

Comment: Doesn't say anything about the protocol,  unfortunately. Must it be SSH and not FTPS?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to pass only folder path of server and do not specify file name in that path.

oSftp.Put(LocalDirectory + "/" + FileName, _ftpDirectory);

and also make sure you have added below packages from nuget

Install-Package DiffieHellman
Install-Package Org.Mentalis.Security

Answer (score 0):

just check your path of file and path where you want to upload on `sftp`.

example:

```
Sftp sftp=new Sftp("host","username","pass");
sftp.Connect();

sftp.Put("path of your local file","path to upload file on sftp server");

sftp.Close();
```